# A version of "read" that doesn't require quoted strings

Tags: haskell

In my app I'm doing a lot of conversions from `Text` to various datatypes, often just to `Text` itself, but sometimes to other datatypes.

I also rarely do conversions from other string types, e.g. `String` and `ByteString`.

Interestingly, [`Readable.fromText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/readable-0.3.1/docs/Data-Readable.html) does the job for me, at least for `Integer` and `Text`. However I also now need `UTCTime`, which `Readable.fromText` doesn't have an instance for (but which I could write myself).

I was thinking that `Readable.fromText` was a `Text` analogy of `Text.Read.readEither` for `[Char]`, however I've realised that `Readable.fromText` is actually subtlety different, in that `readEither` for text isn't just `pure`, but instead expects the input string to be quoted. This isn't the case however for reading integers however, who don't expect quotes.

I understand that this is because `show` shows strings with quotes, so for read to be consistent it needs to require quotes.

However this is not the behaviour I want. I'm looking for a typeclass where reading strings to strings is basically the `id` function.

`Readable` seems to do this, but it's misleadingly named, as its behaviour is not entirely analogous to `read` on `[Char]`. Is there another typeclass that has this behaviour also? Or am I best of just extending `Readable`, perhaps with newtypes or alternatively PRs?

Comment: I probably have as many `Parseable` classes as I do Haskell repos. Okay, maybe not quite that many -- but I wouldn't be surprised if it's half as many classes as repos.

Comment: If you redefine `read :: String -> String` to be `id`, how is e.g. `read :: String -> (String, String)` supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

## The what

Just use [Data.Text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.1/docs/Data-Text.html) and [Data.Text.Read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.1/docs/Data-Text-Read.html#v:decimal) directly

With `signed decimal` or just `decimal` you get a simple and yet expressive minimalistic parser function. It's directly usable:

```
type Reader a = Text -> Either String (a, Text)
decimal :: Integral a => Reader a 
signed :: Num a => Reader a -> Reader a
```

Or you cook up your own `runReader :: Reader a -> M a` combinator for some M to possibly handle non-empty leftover and deal with the Left case.

For turning a `String -> Text`, all you have to do is use [pack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:pack)

## The why

Disclaimer: The matter of parsing data the right way is answered differently depending on who you ask.

I belong to the school that believes typeclasses are a poor fit for parsing mainly for two reasons.

###### Typeclasses limit you to one instance per type

You can easily have two different time formats in the data. Now you might tell yourself that you only have one use case, but what if you depend on another library that itself or transitively introduces another `instance Readable UTCTime`? Now you have to use newtypes for no reason other than be able to select a particular implementation, which is not nice!

###### Code transparency

You cannot make any inference as to what parser behavior you get from a typename alone. And for the most part haddock instance documentation often does not exist because it is often assumed the behavior be obvious.

Consider for example: What will `instance Readable Int64` do?

- Will it assume an ASCII encoded numeric representation? Or some binary representation?
- If binary, which endianness is going to be assumed?
- What representation of signedness is expected? In ASCII case perhaps a minus? Or maybe with a space? Or if binary, is it going to be one-complement? Two-complement?
- How will it handle overflow?

###### Code transparency on call-sites

But the intransparency extends to call-sites as well. Consider the following example

```hs
do fieldA <- fromText
   fieldB <- fromText
   fieldB <- fromText
   pure T{..}
```

What exactly does this do? Which parsers will be invoked? You will have to know the types of `fieldA`, `fieldB` and `fieldB` to answer that question. Now in simple code that might seem obvious, but you might easily forget if you look at the same code 2 weeks from now. Or you have more elaborate code, where the types involves are inferred non-locally. It becomes hard to follow which instance this will end up selecting (and the instance can make a huge difference, especially if you start newtyping for different formats. Say you cannot make any inference from a field name `fooTimestamp` because it might perhaps be `UnixTime` or `UTCTime`)

And much worse: If you refactor and alter one of the field types data declaration from one type to another - say a time field from `Word64` to `UTCTime` - this might silently and unexpectedly switch out to a different parser, leading to a bug. Yuk!

## On the topic of Show/Read

By the way, the reason why show/read behave they way they do for Prelude instances and deriving-generated instances can be discovered in the [Haskell Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18600011.4).

On the topic of `show` it says

> The result of show is a syntactically correct Haskell expression
> containing only constants [...]

And equivalently for `read`

> The result of show is readable by read if all component types are readable.
> (This is true for all instances defined in the Prelude but may not be true
> for user-defined instances.) [...]

So show for a string `foo` produces `"foo"` because that is the syntactically valid Haskell literal representing the string value of `foo`, and `read` will read that back, acting as a kind of `eval`